# problems with zpl2- zpl2 import ZPLDocument, ZPLLabel

Tags: python, zpl-ii

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pured\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\impressao_zpl\impressao_zpl.py", line 6, in <module>
    from zpl2 import ZPLDocument, ZPLLabel
ImportError: cannot import name 'ZPLDocument' from 'zpl2' (C:\Users\pured\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\zpl2.py)
```

I attempted to implement a Python script for printing `ZPL` labels using the `zpl2` library. I expected the script to successfully import the necessary modules, read `ZPL` files, and send them to a printer using the `qz-tray` tool. However, upon execution, I encountered import errors related to the `ZPLDocument` class from the zpl2 library, preventing the script from functioning as intended. I have been troubleshooting the issue by verifying library versions, checking for potential conflicts, and exploring code adjustments. My goal is to resolve these import errors and achieve successful ZPL label printing using the script.